# Installing Ubuntu on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a Virtual Machine from a disc that has the OS on it. However whenever I attempt to install Ubuntu onto the Virtual Machine, I get the following:

"You need at least 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu.

This computer only has 8.6 GB."

I have 10,000MB of base memory on the Virtual Machine, so what is the problem here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Recommended base memory is about 4000MB as seen in VIrtualBox. Why is yours 10000MB?

Comment: @George I had it at 4000 previously, but I changed it when I encountered this issue. Should I put it back at 4000?

Comment: The message is about disk space, not memory. Have you defined a big enough virtual disk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is about disk space of your virtual disk.
Delete the currrent virtual disk (vdi ?) inside your Virtual Machine settings, create a new one, and give it more space, for example 20 Gb of disk space.

The virtual RAM has nothing to do with this, but for completeness :
Recommended base memory depends on how much RAM your machine has. 
e.g. when your computer would have 2 Gb RAM total, it would be tricky to give a Virtual Machine more than 1.5 Gb RAM.